# Why am I getting stackoverflow exception in this helper function of quicksort?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to solve following problem using Quicksort.

I have *n* string in an array where each string is guaranteed to be positive positive number with no leading zeros and digits between 1 and 10^6 inclusive. I did it using regular quicksort with `BigInteger` struct but I've got a lot of timeout cases which led me to think I need to optimize my way of comparisons and drop the parsing from `string[]` and back to `BigInteger[]` and back to `string[]` so I've decided to sort it as it is. Here is my code:

```
static void swap(string[] array, int first, int second)
{
    var temp = array[first];
    array[first] = array[second];
    array[second] = temp;
}

static void quickSort(string[] array, int left, int right)
{
    if (left >= right) return;
    var pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
    var index = partition(array, left, right, pivot);
    quickSort(array, left, index - 1);
    quickSort(array, index, right);
}

static int partition(string[] array, int left, int right, string pivot)
{
    while(left <= right)
    {
        while (left < array.Length && !array[left].IsBigger(pivot)) left++;
        while (right < array.Length && array[right].IsBigger(pivot)) right--;
        if (left <= right)
        {
            swap(array, left, right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    return left;
}

static bool IsBigger(this string a, string b)
{
    if (a.Length < b.Length) return false;
    else if(a.Length > b.Length) return true;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > b[i]) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But then I am getting SO exception in `IsBigger` function when the input is so small as `[ "31415926535897932384626433832795", "1", "3", "10", "3", "5" ]` and I can't seem to try why.

There is no funny moments calling quicksort - this is how I do it `quickSort(unsorted, 0, unsorted.Length - 1);`

---

### What I've tried so far

- Sounds crazy but I've tried to force .NET ensure that this method needs more stack size as to me everything looks okay by calling `RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack();` in `IsBigger` but didn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I was fool to believe *x > y == !(x < y)* when it really should have been *x > y == x <= y*. Pay attention to the classes of discrete mathematics guys.

This let me introduce another helper method

```
static bool IsLessThan(this string a, string b)
    => a.Equals(b) ? false : !a.IsBigger(b);
```

ultimately changing partition method to

```
static int partition(string[] array, int left, int right, string pivot)
{
    while (left <= right)
    {
        while (array[left].IsLessThan(pivot)) left++;
        while (array[right].IsBigger(pivot)) right--;
        if (left <= right)
        {
            swap(array, left, right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with IsBigger

"1234".IsBigger("1235") 
and
"1235".IsBigger("1234")

both return false.

The else clause in the loop should be removed.

Comment: That's not an issue for the sorting algorithm, since it's still a consistent comparison function, if likely not the desired one.

Comment: Exactly.  You have to keep checking all the digits when they are equal.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You don't understand why faulty comparison logic will cause a sort to fail?

Comment: owww now I get it

Comment: @juharr I don't see how it's a faulty comparison in the mathematical sense sorting relies on. It simply treats all those strings as equal.

Comment: @CodesInChaos he is write, I really need to treat them as numbers, else clause is wrong, because I am leaving the method too early.

Comment: This doesn't fix the SO exception problem tho

Comment: @.kuskmen This function will result in an array sorted differently than you want (all strings with same length and same first char are considered equal and thus output in unspecified order). But since it's a valid comparison function (describing a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) in the mathematical sense) cannot cause infinite recursion, endless loops, out of bounds reads and all the weirdness you're experiencing due to bugs in the sorting algorithm. Contrary to @juarr is claiming, it cannot *cause a sort to fail*.

Comment: Agree, this is not the answer to exception I am facing right now.

Comment: @CodesInChaos To be fair, your original comment (before edit) basically just said "this is not a problem."  I think most people would disagree that a faulty comparison is not a problem for a sorting algorithm, even if it doesn't cause infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this is never happening

```
if (left >= right) return;
```

You are never returning. And so you recurse forever and overflow your stack. Use your debugger to find out why you right is always > left

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this instead and adjust your "IsBigger"extension method to what you want:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void swap(string[] array, int first, int second)
        {
            var temp = array[first];
            array[first] = array[second];
            array[second] = temp;
        }

        static void quickSort(string[] array, int left, int right)
        {
            int i = left, j = right;
            var pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];

            while (i <= j)
            {
                while (array[i].IsBigger(pivot))
                {
                    i++;
                }

                while (array[j].IsBigger(pivot))
                {
                    j--;
                }

                if (i <= j)
                {
                    // Swap                    
                    swap(array, i, j);

                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }

            // Recursive calls
            if (left < j)
            {
                quickSort(array, left, j);
            }

            if (i < right)
            {
                quickSort(array, i, right);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var array = new[] { "31415926535897932384626433832795", "1", "3", "10", "3", "5" };

            // Print the unsorted array
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            quickSort(array, 0, array.Length - 1);

            // Print the sorted array
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static bool IsBigger(this string a, string b)
        {
            if (a.Length < b.Length) return false;
            else if (a.Length > b.Length) return true;

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] > b[i]) return true;

                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```